# Remove tint from UISegmentedControl images iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl which has 3 images rather than text. 
The images are all colored however the UISegmentedControl forces a tint on them which simply overrides their colors to blue or whatever color the tint is.
Giving it a tint of `UIColor.clear` makes the images completely transparent.
From what I have gathered by reading various posts on here is that in case of a UIButton, removing the tint is done by setting the Type to Custom instead of System but I don't see this option for UISegmentedControl.
Is this a limitation? Should I use regular UIButtons instead? Any other work arounds?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way what you can do is set Render mode of your Image to `Original Image`. To set this select your image in `Assets`, after that in `Attributes Inspector` set `Render As` to `Original Image`, check below image for reference.

[image]

**Output:**

**Before changing render mode**

[image]

**After changing render mode**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You saved me after a 2 hour search :)